CalculateUntilAsyncQUeriesDone not working
var sw = new StopWatch();
sw.Start();

wk.RefreshAll();

wk.Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone();

sw.Stop();

So I have dotnet console application that is supposed to generate excel reports from some excel templates. It sets new parameter values for the queries in a report and refreshes the connections asynchronously. These queries are set to refresh in the background but I couldn't get the refresh to complete until during a debug session I set a break point and waited for a minute.
I am confused because I though CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone function was supposed to allow execution to complete. Is there another way? I've checked the documentation on microsoft learn and didn't see anything.
